# Combinatorics-Sum over cyclic permutations in QFT

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, quantum-field-theory

Studying Feynman diagrams in 1+1 dimensions, I found the following sum over cyclic permutations

$f(a,b,c,d,e,f)=\sum_{cycl. \{a,b,c\}}\sum_{cycl. \{d,e,f\}}\frac{abd}{(a+b)(a-d)(b-d)}$.

Then  you can check with Mathematica (already not totally trivial) that the if
 $$a+b+c=d+e+f~~~(1)$$
 and
 $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{f}~~~(2)$$
the function $f(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ becomes $f(a,b,c,d,e,f)=1+\frac{abc}{(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)}$.
How can I prove this identity without resorting to brute force?

The relations $(1,2)$ are energy and momentum conservation. For more information about the QFT background see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810026.

Comment: what do you mean precisely by brute force ? one can script some lines to reduce the difficulty. Is it brute force ?

Comment: $f(a,b,c,d,e,f)=1+\frac{abc}{(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)}$ or else $f(a,b,c,d,e,f)=1+\sum_{cycl. \{a,b,c\}}\sum_{cycl. \{d,e,f\}} \frac{abc}{(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)}$

Comment: Find say d and e using (1) and (2) as functions of the other variables, then sum over all the 9 permutations and ask your laptop to fullsimplify.